# Nopcommerce Error in service registration for new table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, nopcommerce

Please help me out. I am stuck with the service registration. I tried every possible aspect from google but could not conclude. What I am trying to do is create a new table EducationDegree, a master table. The Consumer will then be assigned Education degree.
My issue is with the EducationDegreeService registration.  Please see constructor created in Nop.web>Controllers> CustomController.cs and registration done in Nop.web>Framework> dependencyregister.cs. Additional code commented as 
            //Added By Shyam
It’s been more than a week and I have not been able to crack it. So please help me out.

**Below here is the error message**

None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Nop.Web.Controllers.CustomerController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Nop.Services.EducationDegrees.EducationDegreeService educationDegreeService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Nop.Services.Authentication.IAuthenticationService, Nop.Services.Helpers.IDateTimeHelper, Nop.Services.Helpers.DateTimeSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Tax.TaxSettings, Nop.Services.Localization.ILocalizationService, Nop.Core.IWorkContext, Nop.Core.IStoreContext, Nop.Services.Stores.IStoreMappingService, Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerService, Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerAttributeParser, Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerAttributeService, Nop.Services.Common.IGenericAttributeService, Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerRegistrationService, Nop.Services.Tax.ITaxService, Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.RewardPointsSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.CustomerSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Common.AddressSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Forums.ForumSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderSettings, Nop.Services.Common.IAddressService, Nop.Services.Directory.ICountryService, Nop.Services.Directory.IStateProvinceService, Nop.Services.Orders.IOrderTotalCalculationService, Nop.Services.Orders.IOrderProcessingService, Nop.Services.Orders.IOrderService, Nop.Services.Directory.ICurrencyService, Nop.Services.Catalog.IPriceFormatter, Nop.Services.Media.IPictureService, Nop.Services.Messages.INewsLetterSubscriptionService, Nop.Services.Forums.IForumService, Nop.Services.Orders.IShoppingCartService, Nop.Services.Authentication.External.IOpenAuthenticationService, Nop.Services.Catalog.IBackInStockSubscriptionService, Nop.Services.Media.IDownloadService, Nop.Core.IWebHelper, Nop.Services.Logging.ICustomerActivityService, Nop.Core.Domain.Media.MediaSettings, Nop.Services.Messages.IWorkflowMessageService, Nop.Core.Domain.Localization.LocalizationSettings, Nop.Web.Framework.UI.Captcha.CaptchaSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.ExternalAuthenticationSettings, Nop.Services.EducationDegrees.EducationDegreeService)'

**And here is the code I have added**

**Nop.Core>Domain >Educationdegrees**

```
using Nop.Core.Domain.Localization;

namespace Nop.Core.Domain.EducationDegrees
{
   public partial class EducationDegree: BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the page size
        /// </summary>
        public int PageSize { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether customers can select the page size
        /// </summary>
        public bool AllowCustomersToSelectPageSize { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the available customer selectable page size options
        /// </summary>
        public string PageSizeOptions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Nop.Data>Mapping>Education Degree – EducationDegreeMap.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using Nop.Core.Domain.EducationDegrees;

namespace Nop.Data.Mapping.EducationDegrees
{
    public partial class EducationDegreeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EducationDegree>
    {
        public EducationDegreeMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("EducationDegree");
            this.HasKey(v => v.Id);
            this.Property(v => v.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Nop.Services>EducationDegree>EducationDegreeService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Data;
using Nop.Core.Domain.EducationDegrees;
using Nop.Services.Events;

namespace Nop.Services.EducationDegrees
{
    public partial class EducationDegreeService : IEducationDegreeService
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly IRepository<EducationDegree> _educationdegreeRepository;
        private readonly IEventPublisher _eventPublisher;

        #endregion

        #region Ctor

        /// <summary>
        /// Ctor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="educatioRepository">Vendor repository</param>
        /// <param name="eventPublisher">Event published</param>
        public EducationDegreeService(IRepository<EducationDegree> educationdegreeRepository,
            IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
        {
            this._educationdegreeRepository = educationdegreeRepository;
            this._eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all vendors
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="showHidden">A value indicating whether to show hidden records</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">Page index</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">Page size</param>
        /// <returns>Vendors</returns>
        public virtual IPagedList<EducationDegree> GetAllEducationDegrees(int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue, bool showHidden = false)
        {
            var query = _educationdegreeRepository.Table;
            query = query.OrderBy(v => v.Name);

            var educationdegrees = new PagedList<EducationDegree>(query, pageIndex, pageSize);
            return educationdegrees;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Nop.Services>EducationDegree>IEducationDegreeService.cs**

```
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Domain.EducationDegrees;

namespace Nop.Services.EducationDegrees
{
    public partial interface IEducationDegreeService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all vendors
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="showHidden">A value indicating whether to show hidden records</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">Page index</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">Page size</param>
        /// <returns>Vendors</returns>
        IPagedList<EducationDegree> GetAllEducationDegrees(int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue, bool showHidden = false);

    }
}
```

**Nop.Web>Infrastructure>DependencyRegister.cs**

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;
using Nop.Core.Caching;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
using Nop.Core.Infrastructure.DependencyManagement;
using Nop.Web.Controllers;
using Nop.Web.Infrastructure.Installation;
using Nop.Services.EducationDegrees;

namespace Nop.Web.Infrastructure
{
    public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
    {
        public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder)
        {
            //we cache presentation models between requests
            builder.RegisterType<BlogController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<CatalogController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<CountryController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<CommonController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<NewsController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<PollController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<ProductController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<ShoppingCartController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<TopicController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
            builder.RegisterType<WidgetController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));

            //installation localization service
            builder.RegisterType<InstallationLocalizationService>().As<IInstallationLocalizationService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            //Added by Shyam
            builder.RegisterType<EducationDegreeService>().As<IEducationDegreeService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get { return 2; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Nop.Web>Models>EducationDegrees**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FluentValidation.Attributes;
using Nop.Web.Framework;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Localization;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc;

namespace Nop.Web.Models.EducationDegrees
{

    public partial class EducationDegreeModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
        public EducationDegreeModel()
        {
        }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Education Degree")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


}
```

**Nop.Web>Models>Customer>registerModel.cs**

```
public RegisterModel()
        {
            this.AvailableTimeZones = new List<SelectListItem>();
            this.AvailableCountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
            this.AvailableStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
            this.CustomerAttributes = new List<CustomerAttributeModel>();
            //Added By Shyam
            this.AvailableEducationDegrees = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
//Added By Shyam
public int? EducationDegreeId { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableEducationDegrees { get; set; }
```

Nop.Web>Models>Customer>customerinfoModel.cs

```
//Added by Shyam

        [NopResourceDisplayName("What is the highest educational degree that you have obtained (select one)?")]
        public int? EducationDegreeId { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableEducationDegree { get; set; }
```

**Nop.web>Controllers> EducationDegreeController.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors;
using Nop.Services.EducationDegrees;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Controllers;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Kendoui;

namespace Nop.Web.Controllers
{
    public partial class EducationDegreeController : BasePublicController
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly IEducationDegreeService _educationdegreeService;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public EducationDegreeController(IEducationDegreeService educationdegreeService)
        {
            this._educationdegreeService = educationdegreeService;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        //list
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Nop.web>Framework> dependencyregister.cs**

```
//Added by Shyam
using Nop.Services.EducationDegrees;
namespace Nop.Web.Framework
{
    public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
    {
public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder)
        {
.  . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . .

//Added by Shyam
            builder.RegisterType<EducationDegreeService>().As<IEducationDegreeService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
}
}
```

**Nop.web>Controllers> CustomController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Nop.Web.Models.Customer;
//Added by shyam
using Nop.Services.EducationDegrees;

namespace Nop.Web.Controllers
{
    public partial class CustomerController : BasePublicController
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly ExternalAuthenticationSettings _externalAuthenticationSettings;

        //Added by Shyam
        private readonly  IEducationDegreeService _educationdegreeService;
        #endregion

        #region Ctor

        public CustomerController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService,
            IDateTimeHelper dateTimeHelper,
            DateTimeSettings dateTimeSettings, 
            TaxSettings taxSettings,
            ILocalizationService localizationService,
            IWorkContext workContext,
            IStoreContext storeContext,
            IStoreMappingService storeMappingService,
            ICustomerService customerService,
            ICustomerAttributeParser customerAttributeParser,
            ICustomerAttributeService customerAttributeService,
            IGenericAttributeService genericAttributeService,
            ICustomerRegistrationService customerRegistrationService,
            ITaxService taxService, RewardPointsSettings rewardPointsSettings,
            CustomerSettings customerSettings,AddressSettings addressSettings, ForumSettings forumSettings,
            OrderSettings orderSettings, IAddressService addressService,
            ICountryService countryService, IStateProvinceService stateProvinceService,
            IOrderTotalCalculationService orderTotalCalculationService,
            IOrderProcessingService orderProcessingService, IOrderService orderService,
            ICurrencyService currencyService, IPriceFormatter priceFormatter,
            IPictureService pictureService, INewsLetterSubscriptionService newsLetterSubscriptionService,
            IForumService forumService, IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService,
            IOpenAuthenticationService openAuthenticationService, 
            IBackInStockSubscriptionService backInStockSubscriptionService, 
            IDownloadService downloadService, IWebHelper webHelper,
            ICustomerActivityService customerActivityService, MediaSettings mediaSettings,
            IWorkflowMessageService workflowMessageService, LocalizationSettings localizationSettings,
            CaptchaSettings captchaSettings, ExternalAuthenticationSettings externalAuthenticationSettings, EducationDegreeService educationDegreeService)
        {
            //Added by Shyam
            this._educationdegreeService = educationDegreeService;

            this._authenticationService = authenticationService;
            this._dateTimeHelper = dateTimeHelper;
            this._dateTimeSettings = dateTimeSettings;
            this._taxSettings = taxSettings;
            this._localizationService = localizationService;
            this._workContext = workContext;
            this._storeContext = storeContext;
            this._storeMappingService = storeMappingService;
            this._customerService = customerService;
            this._customerAttributeParser = customerAttributeParser;
            this._customerAttributeService = customerAttributeService;
            this._genericAttributeService = genericAttributeService;
            this._customerRegistrationService = customerRegistrationService;
            this._taxService = taxService;
            this._rewardPointsSettings = rewardPointsSettings;
            this._customerSettings = customerSettings;
            this._addressSettings = addressSettings;
            this._forumSettings = forumSettings;
            this._orderSettings = orderSettings;
            this._addressService = addressService;
            this._countryService = countryService;
            this._stateProvinceService = stateProvinceService;
            this._orderProcessingService = orderProcessingService;
            this._orderTotalCalculationService = orderTotalCalculationService;
            this._orderService = orderService;
            this._currencyService = currencyService;
            this._priceFormatter = priceFormatter;
            this._pictureService = pictureService;
            this._newsLetterSubscriptionService = newsLetterSubscriptionService;
            this._forumService = forumService;
            this._shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
            this._openAuthenticationService = openAuthenticationService;
            this._backInStockSubscriptionService = backInStockSubscriptionService;
            this._downloadService = downloadService;
            this._webHelper = webHelper;
            this._customerActivityService = customerActivityService;


            this._mediaSettings = mediaSettings;
            this._workflowMessageService = workflowMessageService;
            this._localizationSettings = localizationSettings;
            this._captchaSettings = captchaSettings;
            this._externalAuthenticationSettings = externalAuthenticationSettings;


        }
}}
```

Comment: The only issue I can think of in this code is the instance scope of dependencies, like you have used, InstancePerLifetimeScope, give it a try by using InstancePerHttpRequest. I don't have much knowledge on instance scopes but if it does resolve your issue than we can dig it down.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Any I figure out the issue to be with Nop.Web.Controllers constructor declaration. Instead of  declaring "EducationDegreeService educationDegreeService" i should have used " IEducationDegreeService educationDegreeService".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are Right user3838557 :

Nop.Web.Controllers constructor declaration.

**Instead of declaring**

"EducationDegreeService educationDegreeService"

**You should have used**

IEducationDegreeService educationDegreeService"